# A simple derivation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry

During the study of a paper I see that its author defines
$$\frac{dh^{ab}}{d\tau}:=h^{am}h^{bn}\frac{dh_{mn}}{d\tau}$$
and from this concludes that
$$\frac{d}{d\tau}(h^{ab})=\frac{d}{d\tau}(h^{am}h^{bn}h_{mn})=-\frac{dh^{ab}}{d\tau}$$

where $h_{ab}$ is a Riemannian metric that depends on the parameter $\tau$.
I Can not derive last equation. Can someone point me in the right direction? Sorry, if my question is very obvious!

Comment: Might be relevant to cite the paper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have a lowered index on the RHS:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dh_{ab}}{dt} &= \frac{d}{dt}\left(h_{ma}h_{nb}h^{mn}\right)\\
&=\frac{dh_{ma}}{dt}\delta_{b}{}^{m} + \frac{dh_{nb}}{dt}\delta_{a}{}^{n} + h_{ma}h_{nb}\frac{dh^{mn}}{dt}\\
\frac{dh_{ab}}{dt}&= 2 \frac{dh_{ab}}{dt} + h_{ma}h_{nb}\frac{dh^{mn}}{dt}\\
\frac{dh_{ab}}{dt} &= -h_{ma}h_{nb}\frac{dh^{mn}}{dt}
\end{align}$$